# Django Image resizing script

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a project that the images upload and save in a sub folder in the media and never set an image size so now the images save 4mb and ended up totalling to 40GB in size.

I know how to write a script if the images were in a single folder but could someone guide me to do this to check all images in a folder and resize it ? Even if its in a sub folder and another sub folder.

Using Django and python

**Function for image upload**

```
def artwork_theme_name(instance, filename):
    path, name = get_hashed_upload_to(instance.id, filename)
    return 'theme/{}/{}'.format(path, name)
```

**Upload model**

```
class ArtworkForeground(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(_("description"))
    foreground = models.ImageField(_("foreground image"), upload_to=artwork_theme_name)
```

Comment: It would be better if you do resize the image while saving

Comment: I know, fixing someone else' mess up. Trying to resize the current images smaller.

Comment: can you add the corresponding models?

Comment: So all images are of the `ArtworkForeground` model? How do you want to*resize* them (with a fixed resolution?)

Comment: Yes ArtworkForeground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I'm **overwrite** the existing image with **reduced size** image. The **`artwork.foreground`** is a `file-pointer` and we passed the fp to the `PIL` class. The **`save()`** method of `Image` class takes filename/path-conatining-filename as first argument. At that point the **`.path`** attribute became handy

```
from PIL import Image


def do_resize(image):
    pil_img = Image.open(image)
    resize_limit = 100, 150
    pil_img.thumbnail(resize_limit, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pil_img.save(image.path)


for artwork in ArtworkForeground.objects.filter(foreground__isnull=False):
    do_resize(artwork.foreground)
```

**UPDATE-1**
Where should I put this snippet?

> If you set some kind of ***restriction*** or ***validation*** from **Now Onwards**, just run this script in your **Django Shell** ( This is only for a one time use)

Comment: If you set some kind of ***restriction*** or ***validation*** from **Now Onwards**, just run this script in you **Django Shell** ( This is only for a one time use)

Comment: Just getting this error but it is imported: NameError: name 'Image' is not defined

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: So in the follwing screenshot you can see my code, the script I am running and the error and also on the left where I put the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/za4dnfto79zkt6p/Screenshot%20from%202018-08-22%2012-05-51.png?dl=0

Comment: @Darren open the shell, and paste the code line by line, ***with proper indentation***

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`os.walk()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/os.walk) function to go through all files and subfolders.

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, file)
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            resize_image(filename)
```

Comment: Let me try this, looks promising :)